# Understanding batch_size in CNNs

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network

Say that I have a CNN model in Pytorch and 2 inputs of the following sizes:

- **input_1:** [2, 1, 28, 28]
- **input_2:** [10, 1, 28, 28]

**Notes**:

- To reiterate, input_1 is batch_size == 2 and input_2 is batch_size == 10.
- *Input_2* is a superset of *input_1*. That is, *input_2* contains the 2 images in *input_1* in the same position.

**My question is**: how does the CNN process the images in both inputs? I.e. does the CNN process every image in the batch sequentially? Or does it concatenate all of the images in the batch size and then perform convolutions per usual?

The reason I ask is because:

- The output of CNN(input_1) != CNN(input_2)[:2]

That is, the difference in batch_size results in slightly different CNN outputs for both inputs **for the same positions**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CNN is a general term for convolutional neural networks. Depending on the particular architecture it may do different things. The main building blocks of CNNs are [convolutions](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/nn.html#conv2d) which do not cause any "crosstalk" between items in batch and pointwise nonlinearities like [ReLU](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/nn.html#torch.nn.ReLU) which do not either. However, most architectures also involve other operations, such as normalization layers - arguably the most popular is [batch norm](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/nn.html#batchnorm2d) which **does** introduce crosstalk. Many models will also use [dropout](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/nn.html#dropout2d) which behaves stochastically outside of [eval](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/nn.html#torch.nn.Module.eval) mode (by default models are in [train](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/nn.html#torch.nn.Module.train) mode). Both above effects could lead to the observed outcome above, as well as other custom operations which could cause cross-talk across the batch.

Aside from that, because of [numeric precision](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/notes/randomness.html#pytorch) issues, your code may not give *exactly* the same results, even if it doesn't feature any cross-batch operations. This error is very minor but sufficient to manifest itself when checking with `CNN(input_1) == CNN(input_2)[:2]`. It is better to use [`allclose`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/torch.html#torch.allclose) instead, with a suitable epsilon.

Comment: I tested my CNN model and indeed, cross-talk was introduced by batch_norm. This is very interesting behavior.

Answer (score 4):

Just to add to Jatentaki's nice answer, below is a quick demonstration of the fact that the pure conv2d doesn't introduce "crosstalk" between items in a batch:

```
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F


input_1 = torch.randn((10, 1, 28, 28))
input_2 = input_1[:2]

weight =  torch.randn((16, 1, 3, 3))

conv_1 = F.conv2d(input_1, weight)
conv_2 = F.conv2d(input_2, weight)

>>> torch.equal(conv_1[:2], conv_2)
True
```

So the reason for the discrepancy you get is probably one of the mentioned by Jatentaki (if you could show your CNN model it would help to spot the exact reason).